# Delete multiple lines - from "patternA" match, through second occurrence of "patternB"

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to use `sed` or similar tool to find a line containing "`something?`" and delete that line and all following lines up until the second occurrence of a line containing "`fi`".

Example...

If I have the following file `/somepath/somefile` containing:

```
...

# Test something?
if something
then
do something
if somethingelse
then
do somethingelse
fi
fi

...
```

and I'd like to find and remove all those lines, starting with the line containing "`something?`" through the line containing the second "`fi`"

I'm able to remove all lines starting with the line containing "`something?`" through the end of the file using `sed -n '/something?/q;p'` but I'm not sure how to add a condition to say stop after the second line containing "`fi`". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this with Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { del=0 } /Test something\?/ { del=2 } del<=0 { print } /fi/ { del -= 1 }' your-file
```

Comment: Works very well, thank you! Taught me a bit more about `awk` as well. So, say I wanted to delete up to the first or third or fourth occurrence of `fi` would I simply change that `{ del=2 }`?

Comment: To delete everything up to and including the fourth `fi` you'd need to replace `{ del=2 }` with `{ del=4 }`, yes.

Comment: Perfect, I think I like this solution best because of that.

Comment: @nwk, would you mind elaborating upon your example? How do the "del=" cause lines in between del=0 and del=2 to be deleted? Could you link me to an explanation or perhaps walk through the logic for a few lines? Thanks!

Comment: @newbie Awk programs consist of patterns and actions. The only pattern-action pair that prints anything here is `del<=0 { print }`, which means lines from the input are printed only if the value of `del` is ≤ 0. `BEGIN { del=0 }` sets `del` to zero when Awk starts. `/Test something\?/ { del=2 }` sets `del` to 2 when the regex matches. Once that happens, nothing is printed until the script encounters `fi` twice and `del` is zero again thanks to `/fi/ { del -= 1 }`.