# sed or awk remove multiple lines starting with `if` and ending with that `if`'s closing `fi`

Tags: bash, awk, sed

An extension to this question [Delete multiple lines - from "patternA" match, through second occurrence of "patternB"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502712/delete-multiple-lines-from-patterna-match-through-second-occurrence-of-pat) ... Thinking I should make it more robust.

So, rather than counting how many `fi`'s, in the likelihood there may be an unknown amount, I'd like to be able to simply execute something where...

If I have the following file `/somepath/somefile` containing:

```
...

# Test something?
if something
then
do something
if somethingelse
then
do somethingelse
fi
fi

...
```

...with an unknown amount of possible `if`/`fi` statements, how can I remove everything from the line starting with the string containing "`something?`" through the line containing the closing "`fi`" to the first `if`? Any/All help is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if the `something?` line is not followed immediately by an `if` statement?  It doesn't count, or an arbitrary number of lines can intervene?  What happens if you have `something?` on line 20, `while …; do` on line 21, and `if` on line 22?  There'll be a `done` in the output with no matching `for` or `while`.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you need a parser for this. However, if all of the commands in your script follow the pattern from the sample in the question (`if`/`fi` always at the beginning of the line), this somewhat crude if-counting solution should work.

```
awk 'BEGIN { del=0; level=0 } /Test something?/ { del=1 } del==0 { print } /^if / { level++ } /^fi( |$)/ { level--; if (level == 0) del=0 }' somefile
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, again! That does seem to work, and will work for now. Interesting, though, I see now how the pattern is important. Maybe python is better suited? I'd like to make sure it's robust.

Comment: You're welcome (x2). I am not sure I understand your question, though. Do you mean to ask if Python is better for this task than Awk? If so, I'd say, not necessarily. Awk allows you to express kind of text transformation more concisely because it operates on a per-record basis. You can read [this man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&sektion=1) to understand Awk. It's short and clearly written.

Comment: I simply meant would using a python parser be more robust and handle variability in the structure of the possible if/fi's inside the first if statement. I think this will work, I'll just have to watch my structure.

Comment: @TryTryAgain: It won't matter if you use Python, or Perl, or Ruby, or Bash, or anything else — unless you get into serious parsing of the shell script as a shell script, rather than as text lines with patterns, the result will be delicate.  Making it robust to what people can do in scripts will be hard.  Regexes are an approximation tool; they approximately match what you're after.  If you want to make it rigorous, you have to use parsing instead of regexes.  Can you imagine writing the regexes to handle quoted strings in shell?  Assignments?  Command substitution?  Here docs?  Etc. Not easy!

Comment: Doesn't awk support word boundaries?  `/\<if\>/` or `/\bif\b/`

Comment: @andlrc: It depends on the variant of Awk you're using.  Since it isn't specified which variant is in use, it's safest to assume the answer is "No".

Comment: @andlrc POSIX doesn't guarantee Awk to understand them. See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676846/how-to-use-word-boundaries-in-awk-without-using-match-function.

Comment: @andlrc GNU awk does but that's not going to help much - the OP needs a parser.